# Store Mathematica results in an external rdbms

Tags: external-calls, databases, storage

I want to store Mathematica results in an external rdbms, Postgres specifically.

The Mathematica documentation talks a lot (eg in 'Relational Database Quick Start') about *extracting* data from external databases but very little (to nothing?) that I can see about using external relational databases to *store* information.

It seems to me that to use something like

```
ExternalEvaluate[
 dbConnection,
"INSERT INTO tbl(col1, col2) VALUES "<> calculated_values_as_strings
]
```

is very rough and potentially unsafe.

With Mathematica V12's new `RelationalDatabase` and `EntityStore` objects there *must* be a nicer way to store data in an external RDBS. How is it done?

Is `DatabaseLink` the only solution?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Use [SQLInsert](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/SQLInsert.html) to insert data into a table.  If you have problems with `SQLInsert` we may be able to help you.  Try to provide some minimal code that we can use to reproduce the problem.  Also see the (minimal) example of batch inserting data [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/InsertingData.html).  To see a list of RDB commands, evaluate ```Needs["DatabaseLink`"]; Information["SQL*"]```.

Comment: So, just to be sure, regardless of the new objects  'RelationalDatabase' and 'EntityStore' the only option for submitting to an external database is through `DatabaseLink` and `SQLInsert`?